# How to refer to a class, in a separate file in your main form?

Tags: c#

I am creating a program, and I have a entire class made in a separate file. Now, in my main form I need to refer to that file or else the program does not work. Does anyone know how to refer to the class, or even the file in the main form, so that I can use element from that class in my main form program?

Comment: does class name not available on main form? I mean if you are directly writing the name of class, is it giving any error?

Comment: You should give more detail if you want an answer ASAP. Is this Winforms or web forms or MVC or ... Are these all in the same project? Etc.

Comment: OK here is the deal. Basically, I am making a game. I made a separate file for the game parts, it has one item, which is the board of the game. So, its a separate class which controls the movements of the user moving the game pieces and finding out who wins. In my main form, I would like to call that class, as I am referring to that class in my main form. But I don't exactly understand how? Hopefully, this was not confusing, as I am fairly new to all this c# stuff.

Comment: @user3127761 Instead of a comment, just edit the additional information into your question so everyone is sure to see it (and provide some code examples if you have them).

Comment: I actually kind of get it, since people keep saying to use static. But people can give me an example of when to use static?

Comment: See [C# Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx)

Comment: ok, I was wondering how would you call  method in a separate file in your main form? I am so sorry if I am so very annoying to you, it just I am having much problem with c#! Thanks for anyone who helps!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but you can always declare elements of a class as static too and reference them directly as attributes of the class

for example:

```
public class Automobile
{
    public static int NumberOfWheels = 4;
    public static int SizeOfGasTank
    {
        get
        {
            return 15;
        }
    }
    public static void Drive() { }
    public static event EventType RunOutOfGas;

    // Other non-static fields and properties...
}
```

and then reference the attribute in your code as

```
int i = Automobile.NumberOfWheels;
```

this example was stracted from here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Using static classes and static attributes is a very dirty but commonly used way to get global variables in C#.

hope it helped!